# continuously update value in entry

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I am still beginner in Xamarin .

I created an application to connect with machine using Mobile app ( Xamarin.forms ).

I created a button , when clicked , i receive the data ( number of product produced ) in a Entry ( read only ) .

```
<ContentPage Title="Production Data">
    <StackLayout>

        <Label Text="Packs Produced"></Label>

        <Entry x:Name="Packs" IsReadOnly="True"></Entry>

        <Button x:Name="ReadData" Text="Read" Clicked="ReadData_Clicked"></Button>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Then

```
        private void ReadData_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Packs.Text = string.Format();
    }
```

I need to update the packs.text every 5 sec .

I did the same with another application using windows Form using timer ( when ReadData button is clicked , it enable the timer ) and timer_tick ( to read the data every 5 second).

Could this be done using xiamarin ?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @Jason , hello , can you guide me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did the same with another application using windows Form using timer ( when ReadData button is clicked , it enable the timer ) and timer_tick ( to read the data every 5 second).Could this be done using xiamarin ?

If you want to do something like Timer in Xamarin.forms Android, you could try code below.

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), () =>
{
    // Do something

    return true; // True = Repeat again, False = Stop the timer
});
```

I use the number i to update the value in entry each 5 seconds for your reference.

```
private void ReadData_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
        {
            // Do something
            Packs.Text = i.ToString();

            i++;
            return true; // True = Repeat again, False = Stop the timer
        });
    }
```

[image]

If you want to do more in IOS, UWP, you could check the code in the link.
https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-timer/

Comment: Thanks , it was so easy

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this by easily using **Matcha.BackgroundService** plugin.More info https://github.com/winstongubantes/MatchaBackgroundService

You can initiate the task on every X seconds or minutes using this plugin.

In your button click, You can start the timer service like

```
   private  void Button_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //Register Periodic Tasks
                BackgroundAggregatorService.Add(() => new PeriodicCall(5));

                //Start the background service
                BackgroundAggregatorService.StartBackgroundService();

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () =>
                        {

     Packs.Text = string.Format();
                        });

      }
```

Create a class named **PeriodicCall** and in your Periodic Call

```
public class PeriodicCall : IPeriodicTask
{
    public PeriodicCallTest(int seconds)
    {
        Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
    }

    public TimeSpan Interval { get; set; }

    public Task<bool> StartJob()
    {
        // Messeging center used for updating the value.
        MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(new Object(), "FetchValue");

        return true; 
    }
}
```

In your xaml.cs where you want to get the value

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "FetchValue", async (sender) =>
                {
 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () =>
                        {

     Packs.Text = string.Format();
                        });  



            });
```

Comment: Thanks for help , but when adding the class in the page cs i receive two errors

Comment: 1- Error CS1520 Method must have a return type ( for PeriodicCallTest )
2- Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>' ( for true after return )

Comment: Did you added return true; inside Task ?

Comment: do you mean inside Task<bool> , or inside { }

Comment: yes....inside Task<bool>.. did you checked the documentation I provided?

Comment: I try my best but i think i need to study more , do you recommend something to start with ?
I insert the code of the periodic call after the button click

Comment: @M.AbdEl-Raouf I updated my answer. Please check it

Comment: thanks but i got some errors solved by :- 
1- Adding using System.Threading.Tasks; 
2- Adding Xamarin.Forms; to the top of the class 
3- i changed  public PeriodicCallTest(int seconds) to public PeriodicCall(int seconds) this solve one problem 
Now still the problem of return true ;